# How to get name and get value from select box?

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<select name="code_id" id="code_id">
   <option value="1">Code 1</option>
   <option value="2">Code 2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     var code_id = this.code_id.value; // Get value
     var code_name = this...// Get code name
     alert(code_name); 
});
</script>
```

How to get code name (Code 1, Code 2)

Comment: it would simply be the select tag's value. i.e. $('#code_id').val()

Comment: Do you want to get all values or just the currently selected one? Do you want to get it once or everytime a new value is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Clarify your question*** 
If its the selected option's text you want then :

```
 $("#code_id option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give you all code names:

```
$.each($("#code_id option"), function (i, opt) { console.log($(opt).text())})
```

this will give you selected code name

```
$("#code_id").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
$('#code_id option').each(function() { alert($(this).text()); });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#code_id').change(function(){
     alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
 });
});
```

Comment: What, +1 for using `.change()`??? Those variety of event handlers have (read: are?) being deprecated for `.on()`.

Comment: @BenEverard change is deprecated? since when?

Comment: So deprecated was probably the wrong term, I did kind of question it. Either way jQuery themselves are moving away from `.click()`, `.change()` etc, in favour of `.on()`... the older style event methods currently just call `.on(), these methods will still be available for backwards compatibility. Here's the blog post --> http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector for selecting selected option and `text()` for getting it's texts.

> Selects all elements that are selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var txt = $('#code_id option:selected').text()
});
```

Comment: I am *so* sorry! I thought I was editing my own answer. I have no idea how I came to be editing yours... =(

Comment: This is not what the OP wants

Comment: ok no worries ! but still you have to specify which select(by id or name) ..im afraid this wont work if the page has more than 1 select box

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
$('#code_id option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').html();
```

You may need to do some modifications to suite you problem